# Using shared dependency injection in whole solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, quartz.net

In my solution, I have a main project, a **WebUI** project, and also some supporting sub project, for example **Domain** for database access, quartz project for running scheduled jobs by **Quartz** etc.

Until recently I was using **ninject** successfully in the main project, but now I need to use ninject in other projects also. Can I share the dependencies inside the whole solution, meaning accessing all the beans from everywhere, or I can only access them inside a single project?

I tried to inject them to new projects, but the binding is not found :

```
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

Is it OK, to have more then one ninject kernel inside solution assuming that each will only be used inside single Project? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that a `Kernel` should be one-to-one with an applications entry point.  This is the Composition Root and is the place to define your Ninject Kernel so that it can resolve types for the full object graphs that will be constructed for the application.  The kernel can be constructed from a collection of NinjectModule instances.  The modules are where you define your bindings.  If you have multiple applications that are going to use the type hierarchy you have defined I would create the bindings in custom NinjectModules that live inside your assemblies.  Then depending on your application you can mix and match modules when creating your kernel.  This should help in alleviating duplication of bindings in every application and they will be in a reusable location.

Specifically in your case I would:

- Create a DomainModule and specify all bindings specific to your domain.
- Create a QuartzModule and specify all bindings specific to job scheduling.
- You can create a WebUI module as well but this would only be specific to your WebUI project which is also your composition root.  As a result, it would not be re-usable in future applications.  You can add your bindings directly to the kernel for this project if you want.  If you have a WEB specific project, say with your controllers, etc. you may want to create a module for reference.
- Compose the Kernel in your WebUI project by referencing the modules in your other applications: kernel.Load(new [] { DomainProject.DomainModule, SchedulingProject.JobModule });

[Modules and the Kernel Documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but to have it work you have to create the kernel and the bindings in every single project thay can run. so for ex if you have a web prj a domain logic prj a console app you have to create the kernel inside the web and the console. These 2 prj will reference yhe domain login prj and then it is shared.